# Explain GCC error after using an object accidentally declared as a function

Tags: c++, gcc, most-vexing-parse

The following is a common typo with language newcomers, who think that they are defining an object but are actually declaring a function:

```
struct T
{
   void foo() {}
};

int main()
{
   T obj();
   obj.foo();
}
```

GCC 4.1.2's error is:

```
In function 'int main()':
Line 9: error: request for member 'foo' in 'obj', which is of non-class type 'T ()()'
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Why is the reported type in the message `T ()()`? I'd have expected `T ()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC this is just a compiler bug. GCC 4.4 says `T()` while 4.2 says `T()()` for me.

Comment: Oh, meh. Yea, 4.4.1 gives me the output I expected too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error is best understood when you realize that you usually don't write out function types without naming at least the function, but it's a bit more common for function pointers.

For instance, `int (*fooPtr)()` names the pointer. If you omit the name, you have `int (*)()`. Now, going from function pointer to function type would give you `int ()()`.

There's no real standard here, because ISO C++ doesn't define canonical names for all types. For instance, `const volatile int` is the same type as `volatile const int`, and neither form is canonical.

Comment: OK, but then when you provide a "function type" to, say, std::function, you write `std::function<int()>(...)`.

Comment: Indeed. And in fact `int()()` could (should?) be parsed as a function that returns an `int()` (!). But the question was to explain a GCC error.